# verb tense **were being raised**

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Could you explain a verb tense **were being raised** here and meaning of the second sentence in terms of that upgrading school is not a new school.

> It was an old, inadequate building, painted the traditional red,
>   overcrowded and understaffed. It certainly did need upgrading, and
>   taxes **were being raised** for a new school.

A WIND in the DOOR
MADELEINE L’ENGLE

Answer (score 1):

"to raise taxes" can mean "to collect tax money" or it can mean "to increase tax rates". In either case "were being" should mean that this is in the process of happening. Presumably, gthe intent is that at the end of the process, there will be money for a new school.

"Upgrading" could mean repairing and improving the existing school, or it could mean replacing the existing school with a new, improved school building. I take

> It certainly did need upgrading, and taxes were being raised for a new school.

to mean that the existing school at least needs repair and improvement, if not replacement, and that tax money is being collected, possibly at increased rates, with the intent of replacing the school.

The "and" construction here is just 'one thing after another'. The original sentence could be recast as:

> the school certainly did need upgrading. Taxes were being raised for a new school.

Without additional context, there is no way to know what taxes, or how much money they might raise. Nor can we tell whether the speaker is considering both repair/improvement, or only replacement, nor why. It has been years since I read L'Engle, and I don't recall this passage.

Comment: for me is still difficult to get a sense. why 'and' is used here? I mean the part ', and taxes'. What is taxes here and what is better upgrading or replacing and for whom?

Comment: @Vitaly I have edited the answer to address your comment. See if the edits help.